# How to display a table and its plot side by side with an adjusted height

Tags: plot, streamlit

I’m trying to display a table and its plot side by side in a page.
The goal is that the plot’s height matches with the table’s one !

I tried with [**`st.container`**](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.container) and [**`st.columns`**](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.columns) combined but it does not work (see image below).

```
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px

long_df = px.data.medals_long()

fig = px.bar(long_df, x="nation", y="count",
                color="medal", title="Long-Form Input")

data_container = st.container()

with data_container:
    table, plot = st.columns(2)
    with table:
        st.table(long_df)
    with plot:
        st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

##### `>>> Output (in the web browser)`:

[image]

As you can see, the plot is much longer than the table.
Do you know how to fix this, please ?

**Important detail** : I'm using different tables, so the number of rows is changing constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, neither `st.columns()` nor `st.container` has a `height` parameter. You can achieve this using the `height` parameters of the plotly figure and `st.dataframe()`. When we define height for the dataframe, the user can scroll down to see whole table.

```py
height = 400  # px

fig = px.bar(
    long_df, x="nation", y="count",
    color="medal", title="Long-Form Input",
    height=height,
    )

# update margin to show title on top
fig.update_layout(margin={"t": 30, "b": 0})

data_container = st.container()

with data_container:
    table, plot = st.columns(2)
    with table:
        # use st.dataframe instead of st.table
        st.dataframe(long_df, height=height)
    with plot:
        st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

Another way of visualising data along with the table is to use `st.tabs()`.

```py
tab1, tab2 = st.tabs(["Data", "Chart"])

with tab1:
    st.table(long_df)

with tab2:
    st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

Comment: I opted for your first solution. Thank you so much Kaymal.